# Bootstrap 3: Header creates horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

Firstly here's the link: http://isotopethemes.com/extenso/header-10.html

HTML Code:

```
<header id="header-10">
    </div><!-- /.header-10-top -->
    <!-- MAIN NAVIGATION -->
    <div class="header-10-main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="header-10-logo col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Home 10 Main Logo"></a>
                </div><!-- /.header-10-logo -->
                <div class="header-10-nav col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-10 navigation-10" role="navigation">
                        <ul onClick="" class="zetta-menu zm-response-switch zm-effect-slide-top">
                            <li class="zm-active zm-content-full first">
                                <a href="#">
                                    Home
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="zm-content-full">
                                <a href="#">
                                    Sliders
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="zm-content-full">
                                <a href="#">
                                    Pages
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Portfolio
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="zm-content-full">
                                <a href="#">
                                    Elements
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Blog
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="last">
                                <a href="#">
                                    Contact
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul><!-- /.zetta-menu -->  
                    </nav><!-- /.navbar-10 -->
                </div><!-- /.header-10-nav -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.header-10-main -->
</header><!-- /#header-10 -->
```

If I remove the 'header-10-main' or 'header-10-nav' it solves the problem.

For any resolution below 1370px there is a horizontal scrollbar. I've checked all elements with inspector but none of them exceed the body. Only 'overflow:hidden' works but then the dropdowns don't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the relevant code here

Comment: first of all, dont use duplicate ids: bs-example-navbar-collapse-1

Comment: I've removed the duplicate id, but still the horizontal bar exits

Comment: the zetta-menu is doing the horizontal extend. as it is quite a complex structure, it will take time to find the exact problem.

Comment: col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 is redundant so is col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9, learn the grid system. You only need col-sm-X in both cases. It's disturbing to have people selling themes for Bootstrap and not using correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the width of below element.

```
.zetta-menu .w-150 { 
   width: 140px; // Currently, width: 150px; 
}
```

Better If you can open second level dropdown of blog menu [ Blog -> Blog List ] on left side. Currently it is opening on right side that creates the problem.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I really can't change that style coz it affect many other styles. Thank you for finding the cause of problem. I'll figure it out form here.

Comment: Yes, Better open 2nd level dropdown on left hand side.

Comment: the main issue was the parent listed item did not stretch enough. thank you for finding the problem.